# Trouble With Selection Object in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, selection

I've got some javascript that messes with selections.  The full code does some complicated stuff that I'd rather not go into right now, but I've got a smaller test case I don't understand here.  If you load this page you should see some text and two buttons.

1. Double click on "Some" to select it, and click "Select".  "Some" gets a span around it and becomes gray.
2. Then double click "Some" again and hit "Unselect".  The span goes away, and looking at the page content it looks like it's back to how it started.
3. Double click "Some" one last time, hit "Select" and nothing gets selected.

This last step is failing because the start and end of the selection are reported as being in different nodes on the page, even though it sure looks like the same node, and it is reported as being at position 0 of both nodes.  I don't understand why it's behaving differently than at step 1, because it looks to me like step 2 made the page just like it was before step 1.  After that things get weirder.  There's similar, not quite the same weird behavior in IE9.  In Chrome it's fine.

Anyone know what's going on?  Why are there two different text nodes in step 3?  Why are the offsets of the selections 0 for both, when the selection seems to extend from 0 to 5, like in step 1?

This code has some other bugs and such (trying to do multiple selections fails, lots of other things don't work), but I'm just trying to understand this case as a starting point:

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="text">Some test words</div>
<button onclick='select()'>Select</button>
<button onclick='unselect()'>Unselect</button>
<div id="log"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function log(message)
{
    var log = document.getElementById("log");
    log.innerHTML += message + "<br>";
}
function logSelection(selection)
{
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var startContainer = range.startContainer;
    var endContainer = range.endContainer;
    log("Node types: " + startContainer.nodeType + ", " + endContainer.nodeType + ", " + range.commonAncestorContainer.nodeType)
    log("startContainer: " + (startContainer.nodeType == 3 ? startContainer.wholeText : startContainer.innerHTML));
    log("endContainer: " + (endContainer.nodeType == 3 ? endContainer.wholeText : endContainer.innerHTML));
    log("commonAncestorContainer: " + (range.commonAncestorContainer.nodeType == 3 ? range.commonAncestorContainer.wholeText : escape(range.commonAncestorContainer.innerHTML)));
    log("equal: " + (startContainer == endContainer));
    log("start: " + range.startOffset + " end: " + range.endOffset);
}
function select()
{
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var start = range.startOffset;
    var end = range.endOffset;
    var startContainer = range.startContainer;
    var endContainer = range.endContainer;
    logSelection(selection);
    startContainer.parentNode.innerHTML = startContainer.wholeText.substring(0, start)
        + "<span style='background-color: gray'>"
        + startContainer.wholeText.substring(start, end)
        + "</span>"
        + startContainer.wholeText.substring(end, startContainer.wholeText.length);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    log("");
}
function unselect()
{
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    logSelection(selection);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    var textDiv = $("#text");
    log("start: " + escape(textDiv.html()));
    textDiv.find("span").each(function () {
        var $span = $(this)
        $span.replaceWith($span.html());
    });
    log("final: " + escape(textDiv.html()));
    log("");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I just follow all three step.In last step when  I click select "some"  becomes grey again.Browser:Chrome ,version:43.0.2357.81

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chrome debugger can clearly show where your assumptions go awry:

*Before* taking any action, this is the DOM:

[image: Before]

*After selection*, here's how your script changed it:

[image: After selection]

And finally, after the *"unselection"*:

[image]

This final display reveals the problem: Rather than concatenating the string value nodes, you created a new one.  **The parent `<div>` contains two text nodes**, so your selection will span them.

To be clear, your script here is the problem:

```
textDiv.find("span").each(function () {
    var $span = $(this)
    $span.replaceWith($span.html());
});
```

The replacement of the `span` with the `span`'s `html()` string is what is creating the new text node.